# How to generate a n' number of same characters in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to generate n' number of same characters which will be stored in a var.
Like `gggggggggggggggggggg`

But not using a separate **function**.

Is there any api for that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: What do you mean by `n'`? How is that different from `n`?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @gorak: `console.log('g'.repeat(10));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use repeat function for Strings in JS. It works like this,

```
const str = "some string";
console.log(str.repeat(n));
```

This will repeat str , n number of times

Comment: Already commented under the question. It is a poor question and does not deserve an answer